# hardware support for atomic fetch-and-add vs fetch-and-or

Tags: c++, lock-free

It seems fetch_add is a [win](http://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/atomic_fetch_and_add_vs) (see post comments as well) against a CAS loop on CPUs that support both.

When toggling clear bit(s) to set bit(s) you can use either a bitwise or or an addition operation. The results will be identical. I expect performance for each would be equal. So the decision on which operation to use would hinge on the differences in hardware support for the operations (if any, I failed to turn up any information on relative processor support.)

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other in this case?

Comment: I don't think that fetch-and-add can be used to implement fetch-and-or in general.

Comment: No, but for the specific case I mentioned of setting bits that are already clear there can be no carries - an addition is exactly equal to a bitwise or.

Comment: What I was getting at in my first comment is that even for the case where you want to set bit(s) that are clear, I don't think that fetch-and-add can be used to implement a fetch-and-or to set those (and only those) bits. Imagine that you have two processes that are simultaneously attempting to set the bits. Each could check and find that the bits are currently clear and add the appropriate constant to effectively set those bits; however, the constant would be added twice. I don't see how you can get around that scenario in general (i.e. without planning on carries).

Comment: That's a good point, it didn't occur to me because I have other constraints that prevent two threads from trying to set the same cleared bits (the bits are guaranteed to be clear, use of fetch-and-add or fetch-and-or is to ensure changes are not clobbered by another thread trying to set adjacent bits.)

Comment: Do you care about the original value? If not, you could simply use `LOCK:OR`. If you do care about the original value, then it's probably because you care what changes have been made to the *other* bits. In this case, you could split the one integer field into two. One contains the "other bits" and the other integer field contains the bits that you want to set. You wouldn't need an atomic op to set the bits because of your external synchronization.

Comment: You're right, I could completely eliminate atomic ops by replacing bits with bytes. At an expense of 8x the memory requirements I would have to consider carefully if it's worthwhile.

Comment: Just to clarify: by "prefer one over the other in this case?" do you mean prefer a CAS loop vs a xadd for doing OR on a single bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to do, instead of coding for a specific processor architecture, is to use a compiler intrinsic. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtins), for example, support several atomic builtins, one of which is `__sync_fetch_and_or`.

Since Visual Studio 2005, Visual C++ has supported [`_InterlockedOr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b11125ze%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) [on all architectures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5704bbxw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).